# How can i loop this to do driver.refresh() and retry if it cant find even one of the letters in item?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, selenium, python-2.x

How can i loop this to do `driver.refresh()` and retry if it cant find even one of the letters in item?

```
for i, item in enumerate(myItemLink):
    if 'B' in item:
      if 'l' in item:
        if 'a' in item:
          if 'c' in item:
            if 'k' in item:
              rightItemIndex.append(i)
```

Comment: What do you mean `driver.refresh()`?

Comment: thiss is in a chrome window using chromedriver. driver.refresh() command will just refresh the window. im just wondering how to make it so if even one of those letters isnt found it refreshes and tries again ultil they are all found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want the execute `driver.refresh()` after you have tested for all the letters `'B', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k'` in every item in `myItemLink`, you can use the following:

```
appended = False

while not appended:
    for i, item in enumerate(myItemLink):
        if all([x in item for x in ['B', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k']]):
            rightItemIndex.append(i)
            appended = True
            break
    else:
        driver.refresh()
```